# Should I ask a new question if an existing question is outdated and a bounty was unsuccessful?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I wanted an updated answer to [Achieving bright, vivid colors for an iOS 7 translucent UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897485/achieving-bright-vivid-colors-for-an-ios-7-translucent-uinavigationbar).

One of the bounty notices fit this perfectly:

> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given
>   recent changes.

So, I put 100 of my reputation out there by starting a bounty. I commented on a few of the answers asking if anyone had a solution for the newly released iOS 8.

A week later, I had not gotten a single response, and no new answers were added, so I let the bounty expire.

That question was what I wanted to ask *word for word* except for the iOS 7 part. I want an answer for a newer version of the software.

I can easily copy the source of the question and create a new question with a only slightly modified body and title. But Stack Overflow has taught me that this would get my question closed as a duplicate within minutes.

I understand bounties are not way guaranteeing you get an answer, but I'd like to know what is best for me to do next?

What should I do?

Comment: Another bounty, perhaps?

Comment: @Makoto Another bounty is required to be 200+ reputation, since it would be the second one, and I am not comfortable throwing that much out, after 100 didn't do it.

Comment: Yes, the bounty increases with each offering on it.  However, that would likely be the correct way to go about it; if a bounty of 100 didn't entice anyone, then perhaps a bounty of 200 will.

Comment: @Makoto Easy to say from a 20k user to 2k one.

Comment: @AnubianNoob:  I'm not really saying that because I have more reputation to offer in a bounty.  I'm saying that because that's how the system was implemented, and it makes intuitive sense - if a certain amount of reward wasn't enticing enough, then making it higher *might* be.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not saying it's because you're more experienced, but 200 rep offered on a bounty is 200 rep further from close vote priveleges. That's a solid 10% of all your effort on SO. It's a lot different for low rep users. 10% of everything for a _chance_ that you might get more attention, when it already didn't work.

Comment: I thought we were discussing attaching reputation to a bounty, not privileges.  I believe that the risk when offering bounties is yes, you're going to be further away from privileges that you're close to earning, or you would lose privileges you've already earned if it's sufficiently large enough.  The point isn't about whether or not you'll lose your privilege (which if you've made it this far, you shouldn't have trouble re-earning); it's about **getting attention for a question.**

Comment: @Makoto It didn't work the first time, I have little reason to think it will work a second time.

Comment: Bounties aren't a sure-fire thing.  That's the key to remember. It's meant as an incentive, not something that's sure to get you a response every time.

Comment: @Makoto I understand that. But it didn't get me an answer, so I'm asking what I should do now.

Comment: There is the very real possibility that the question is so uninteresting that it's not going to get an answer, regardless of the number of bounties you put on it, or how many different ways you ask it.  About 1 in 10 questions that don't get closed never get answered.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question has 14 answers and 32K views. I am pretty sure that qualifies it as at least _interesting_. However, the answers to the question are outdated.

Comment: @SantaClaus, I might ask a new Question. Your own question is closely related but not the same as the one you've linked due to the differences you've stated. Make sure to mention and link to the the outdated one and explain clearly why your Question differs in the first few lines of the post to avoid any twitch dup votes (or at least to address the reasoning and let the community decide). Make a well written question and you may get your desired answer. If not you could try offering a bounty on the new Q. The num of answers on the old may put some off answering as it could be seen as answered.

Comment: @indivisible I may ask a new question as you suggest and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean another bounty on the existing Question. I was suggesting one on the new one if you decide to make it. Added bonus that the lower limit drops to 50 again as it would be the first bounty you offered for that Question.

Comment: @indivisible Sorry I didn't catch that until reading your comment the second time :)

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I saw your edit as I was replying but continued anyway. Good luck with however you decide to go. I can't help you sadly; iOS isn't an area I develop in.

Comment: This seems quite similar to the ideas discussed in [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643).

Comment: @Bruno Kindof, but it lacks the bounty part

Comment: Considering that the question already has a number on answers for iOS7, an iOS8-specific answer would probably clutter it. It'd ask a new question mainly for this reason (linking to the iOS7 variant). I've never been primarily motivated by bounties myself, so I might not be representative, but a clear, well explained, new question is more likely to catch my attention than one with a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion, as a new person to SO, I would consider this a new question, as you are discussing a newer platform. That's assuming the solution for IOS7 didn't work.

If I needed a solution for Windows 7, and a solution to a similar question had already been posted for Windows XP, I'd post a new question. Granted, these are much wider differences than between IOS7 and 8, but the principle (I believe) remains the same.