# Good question, old version-dependent answer

Tags: feature-request, old-questions, old-answers

How should we handle highly rated but out-dated answers to still-relevant questions?

Example:
[How to delete a module in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio)
(It's a good 1 year old question with 17,878 views)

Android Studio just left alpha and has been changing weekly for the last year. The above question is still very valid, but the best answer has changed as the tool has evolved.

The best answer for:
v0.1 has 57 upvotes (and is the 'accepted' answer)
v0.5 has 10 upvotes
v0.8 has 1 upvote (from me 10 minutes ago)

In this case, nobody in their right mind would be using an older unstable alpha version, so the accepted & popular answers are just plain old... but the new-correct answer may never surpass the original answer in votes by the time it itself is obsolete. The best answer to this question is the most current one, but it has the least reputation and that probably won't change.

Feature-request - Allow answers to be retroactively tagged with a version.

I know version tagging using the current tag mechanism is frowned-upon ([What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags)) for good reasons, but usability is suffering without a good solution and answer-debt will surely increase over time.

Comment: You'd be surprised what people will do, especially when something's working... However, if there's a newer answer that will be more correct for a later version then edit the current answer to state what versions it's correct for and add another answer with the details for the new version.

Comment: @Ben I'm the one who posted the most recent answer :) But I didn't think to edit the obsolete one. Is that the proper course of action for cases like this? (I generally tend to avoid editing answers, especially accepted/upvoted ones, but maybe this case is different).

Comment: @matiash: As long as the addition is written in professional, neutral language (maybe in _italics_, perhaps _This answer was correct in May 2013 for Android Studio  v0.1, but the best answer changed with v0.5.1 in March 2014, and again with Android Studio v0.8 in July 2014._).  It leaves it clear that the answer was indeed the one that helped the asker (and other people) at the time, but the time has gone past.

Comment: Thanks all for many great comments & answers. Though I'm the 'asker', I probably have the least stackoverflow experience in this discussion... so I'll avoid being 'judge' by marking a correct answer until activity settles down and we see what the community believes is the best approach.

Comment: Related: [Can we bring the <!-​- version --> syntax to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333192/can-we-bring-the-version-syntax-to-stack-overflow/)

Comment: This is a common duplicate target, but a newer development is *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).

Answer (score 54):

You should simply just add a new up-to-date answer to the question, leaving the old answer in place.   Just be clear that your answer is dealing with the newer version of software, and clearly state why there is a difference (if that is not clear already).

Comment: Especially with multiple answers, people will only look at the highest voted answers. I believe this scenario asks for actually editing the high profile answer (on top of this), as @Bruno suggests.

Comment: I don't think you should edit the old answer, as that presumably is still correct wrt the older version as long as the older answer as in this case specifically state what version it relates to -- we can never protect people who does not read (or at least scan) the entire body of information to see that there is a fresher answer

Comment: I don't want to add the new answer into the old answer, just add a disclaimer that makes clear that the answer is correct w.r.t. the old version only

Comment: For the specific question, that is already done as it states it is relevant to `v0.1` -- im not sure how you would determine what version the answer relates to if the author has not already put it in, but if you could and puts in `"version X.X"` then that would be fine as it **improves** the answer, but a fuzzy disclaimer of `"this is for an old version"` would not be ok as it would **not improve** the answer.

Comment: Add a comment or a notification to the original question, but don't change it completely. Downvote it if you don't think it's useful anymore.

Comment: But what if you are an "asker" who believes that the answer might not be the most correct answer today?  This is something I ask myself often.  Questions posted that are duplicates of four year old question are closed as duplicates.  But how does an "asker" elicit new answers to old questions?

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick You can "re-open" old questions by starting a bounty and leaving a comment on the question -- the questions with recent activity will then bubble to the top on the "interesting" list for people to see and provide new answers.   Questions are not closed as duplicate until a number of reviewers has reviewed the closure.

Comment: @Soren Leaving a bounty on an old question is a little bit expensive.  But it's better than not being able to get up-to-date at all.

Answer (score 25):

I'd say there are two possible solutions:

- If you know the tool reasonably well, and think that the new version leads to a different set of problems, sufficient to justify a new question for the new version, **and** if no answer for the new version has been posted yet, it might be worth editing the question to add the version number in the title and description (e.g. "[...] doing this up to version 1.x"). You could subsequently ask a different question stating "from version 2.x". (If necessary, used versioned tags, if appropriate.<sup>(*)</sup>)

  I suspect editing the question this way should be a rare occurrence, since tools or languages rarely change completely, but this happens (e.g. "how do I do X with Python 2.x?" or "[...] Python 3.x?").
- You can also edit the answer to indicate that the answer is outdated. I would edit the answer, and leave a note, at the top, preferably in italics saying something like: "*[Editor's note: this answer was applicable until version 1.x, but version 2.x was released on 1st Jan 2014]*".

  If there already is an answer for the new version, perhaps add a link to it too in your editor's note. It's not clear whether this is always a good idea, though, since you'd effectively provide a bias towards that new answer (whereas other better answers for the new version might appear later). It might be best to leave a comment instead. If this is the accepted answer, I'd leave its author or, better, the asker, be the judge of whether to point to the newer answer. (If the new answer doesn't already say from which version it applies, leave an editor's note in the same way.)

  I guess some people might suggest to downvote the old answer to make the new one come to the top. I don't think I would do that, since this seems rather unfair for the answerer (assuming the answer is correct of course), and that the answer can still be useful to anyone using the old version. (Remember, there are such things as legacy environments, so even in 10 years' time, someone might find the answer for the old version useful if they're confronted with such a system.)

> Feature-request - Allow answers to be retroactively tagged with a version.

Answers are not tagged, questions are. You could potentially already do this in the first case I mention (having a separate question). If you wanted to tag answers, that's a completely different feature. (I personally don't think it's necessary, and it could be quite awkward.)

<sub>(*) Please check with the tagging guidelines separately, since this should generally only be done for cases that justify it.</sub>

Comment: @Bruno I guess it would also depend on how the "tool" is updated. If the way to do something between, say, Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 changes, then two questions seem appropriate, because VS2010 is expected to continue in use long after VS2012 is released. In the case of Android Studio (during alpha), however, it received updates (and auto-updated) almost every other week. I think it wouldn't make much sense to keep questions for alpha versions that are long obsolete, while a generic question with changing current answer seems ok. This is purely my opinion though.

Comment: I made this : https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14420200 edit. Can you please explain why it was rejected and what I should have done to avoid it?

Answer (score 8):

On SE, tags are for searching questions. You want to use tags to attach metadata to an answer ("this applies to a particular version").

This would be useful if there was a need to systematically find such answers, and if we believed there was a good chance the tag would be fairly consistently applied. But there isn't, and we wouldn't be, we just need to warn people of the limited use of the answer.

So, no, not tags, unless there's a more general need for answers to have such markers attached to them.

All that's needed is that the answer clearly indicates that it's out of date, so that future visitors can keep reading for a more recent answer. Edit or comment.

If SO was a wiki, then the right thing to do would be to completely replace the accepted answer with the more up to date solution (or perhaps add the up to date one at the top of the answer and leave the historical solution visible). But it isn't whole-heartedly a wiki, and we don't usually edit an answer in order to completely contradict it. Still I think there's a case for doing exactly that in this situation. If the author doesn't like the up to date solution, they can always roll you back and you'll know that they stand by their out-of-date answer, which you can then downvote with a clear conscience.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in [this similar thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355765/new-answer-then-top-answer-update-then-it-looks-like-duplicate-answers), edit the existing answer to show the new approach. Something like:

> Use this technique: `the new approach`
>
> If you're using version `original version or older`, then use this technique: `the original answer`

This is preferable to adding a new answer because the old answer will already have a lot of upvotes despite being out of date, making it difficult for your new, correct answer to get attention.

Answer (score 1):

We should not edit historical answers that were valid at the time they were written. We can comment. I can tell you this much, the deprecated code (if working) will be very unlikely to be updated.  A good example is HTML. Nobody is going to suggest that billions of lines of code *must* be updated simply because of deprecated (but perfectly valid) syntax. The post must be read as a timeline. Some readers may be developing on "frozen" platforms for legacy enterprise projects on older versions of Oracle, Java, etc. etc.
But do comment, even upon your own answers if you know the syntax has subsequently changed.

Answer (score -12):

I'd suggest being able to flag an answer as outdated so someone with enough points can be alerted and edit it.

I'd also suggest that users who have old accepted answers are emailed (after some time) and asked to verify that their answer still applies.