# Is it OK to edit answers to show that they are obsolete, out-of-date, and deprecated?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

[My edit was rejected.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5289915)  I know sometimes reviews pile on without necessarily being accurate.  Is that what happened here, or was my edit really that wrong?

In my edit's defense: I found the deprecated answer and implemented it.  I didn't see the comments or higher-voted answer before upvoting the accepted and moving on.  If I hadn't accidentally scrolled down some minutes later, I would have a php error log with ****GASP**** *a warning in it*.  Anyway, I thought my edit might help prevent that from happening to someone else.  (*That* being the comments about deprecation, not the warning in the log.)

Comment: Yes, your edit was wrong; please use a comment.

Comment: (Near) Duplicate of: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265433/103167  Notice that the answers there support editing, but in a way that isn't negative about the answer (which was an excellent solution for a particular tool version) and also don't try to "bless" any particular other answer.

Comment: A newer development is *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few things:

1. Usually I would have left a comment in **big bold text** that says

   > **This is now deprecated, see this other answer `<link>`.**

   I have full edit privileges, none of my edits go to the review queue, and yet I still would have been conflicted about editing someone's non-wiki answer like that (adding new information that wasn't part of the original answer).

   When you have full edit privileges, *sometimes* the original poster will let you make an edit like that and not roll it back, but not always.
2. This is a more important point: **just because an answer is accepted, *it does not mean that it is the best answer***.

   Technology, and thus answers, change and become obsolete all the time. It is foolish to just assume that the accepted, or even the top-voted answers, are the best answers on a question.

   When you review answers on Stack Overflow, you still need to vet them yourself, at least a few of them, if not all of them.

Comment: So I edit this answer text to say "OK THIS ONE IS THE RIGHT ANSWER", right?

Comment: @SethBattin since this is a non-wiki answer, I would prefer that you didn't `:P`

Comment: This is completely inappropriate, because it creates the appearance that the answer author is recommending the other answer.  It's sufficient to edit in a note in the accepted answer that it is designed around a specific older version of the language/framework.  Let the best modern answer be suggested by the community via votes, or via a recommendation from the answer author.