# Should information that "[confuses] customers" be removed from answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

Earlier today I stumbled upon [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23930446), which seeks to remove outdated information from an accepted answer, but with a justification that I had never heard before:

> the "does not have support" was confusing customers.

[image: A removal edit with the comment "the 'does not have support' was confusing customers."]

My initial instinct was to reject this edit because it removed a substantial portion of a small answer, and the content it removed was already marked as outdated by the author.

The comment on the suggestion, however, gave me pause. Curious as to who "customers" referred to, I decided to Google the name of the editor. According to [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/luisecabrera), they're not only a Microsoft employee, but the Principal Program Manager for Azure Search, the product at the center of the question whose answer they edited.

After some deliberation, I decided to approve the edit, reasoning that if anyone was qualified to say that an answer was confusing to Azure Search customers, it would be an employee of the company who works with them daily.

Looking back on this, though, I'm not sure I made the right call.

After I approved the edit, I went to the question page and found that the editor had posted their own, new answer just a few minutes before they proposed the edit. Had I known this when I was reviewing, I probably would have rejected their edit and let their answer naturally overtake the old one. But then that begs the question: does the fault lie with me for approving the edit without knowing that they'd posted an alternative answer?

I read through Meta questions including [Is it OK to edit answers to show that they are obsolete, out-of-date, and deprecated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265576/) and [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/) for guidance, but I don't think either of them fully addresses this specific situation.

As I see it, this question is essentially about whether an editor's professional background gives them more credibility when proposing an edit. The two positions that I'm stuck between are:

- Approve - *The editor's knowledge as an Azure Search employee makes them uniquely qualified to suggest this edit.*
- Reject - *The information should have been kept and the edit rejected, no matter who the editor was.*

I'm *very* new to the Suggested Edits queue and I'm eager to learn. Did I make the right decision here?

Comment: eh, I'd be willing to give an employee with authority over the given product a bit more leeway on editing things for this particular purpose. however, with the removal of the old post, the "updated" notation is no longer necessary. (was it necessary to begin with?)

Comment: @KevinB Good point. If I could redo this review, I would probably have edited that notation to something like *“As of May 21, 2018, Azure Files...”*, or just removed it entirely.

Comment: After all, we are here to *help people* right? If that "original answer" really confused people, then I'm fine with removing that obsolete information (just approved that edit too, it's now live)

Comment: I wish more users new to the edit queue would be as vigilant as you have been, you see far too many users who are new to the queue that approve things they shouldn't

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The edit was fine.

The fact that the editor was a Microsoft employee has essentially no bearing on this. What matters is that the edit removed obsolete information that had close to zero chance of ever having any value to any new reader arriving at the question. At best, it avoids future readers being confused. At least, it removes a paragraph of pointless noise. The only reason a reader today might want to see the original answer is for historical research purposes, and they've still got the revision history available to serve that unusual use case.

(Note that if we were dealing with a new release of a programming language or a library that added a previously missing feature, an edit like this would be bad and rejection-worthy, since the original answer - saying that the desired feature doesn't exist - would still be true of older versions and have potential value to readers using them. But that argument doesn't apply to cloud services like Azure. The original answer essentially became 100% false and worthless the instant that Azure released the feature being asked about, and keeping it around helps nobody.)

The fact that the editor also added their own answer doesn't strike me as problematic, nor as relevant to the decision to accept or reject the edit. They chose to add their own answer because they wanted to provide a little bit more detail than the one-sentence answer previously present; that's fine. They also wanted to remove obsolete misinformation from the answer previously present; that's also fine. The two actions have nothing to do with each other.

You did the right thing by approving the edit, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly from a review queue aspect, I can understand rejecting this edit. However, looking more into it, I'd be willing to bet the original author of that answer would have no problem with that edit going through, considering they appear to both be employees for the same product in question.

I would either let the edit through or skip it and allow the original author to decide.

One thing that complicates this though is the editor also posted an answer. If the edit goes through, we'll now have two identical answers. Not sure if that's really a problem though.