# How to handle answers that were right and are now broken due to spec/tech change?

Tags: discussion

I recently used some code on SO as a template for my code. After spending a few hours debugging, I discovered it was due to a change in the spec.

The previously accepted and correct answer (posted after the spec change but presumably before implementation) now doesn't work, as mentioned in the comments. It's got a significant number of upvotes (deserved, as it addresses most aspects correctly). It just doesn't work 5 years later.

In this type of case, is it best to:

1. Edit the answer
2. Post a new answer and comment and hope people notice
3. Something else?

This is trying to be a general question since I didn't see an answer as to what to do. The specific case is [How to add multiple font files for the same font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font/)

Comment: Meh, I'd prefer to see the dupe the other way around then @gnat. This one is of a higher quality and clarity.

Comment: @Bart how about [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) for a dupe target?

Comment: Damn you're good @gnat. Voted.

Comment: Ahh.that look more promising. Thanks gnat.