# How to retire outdated information?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, outdated-information

The first downvote to [my accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061775/python-3-script-to-upload-a-file-to-a-rest-url-multipart-request/8063832#8063832) was righteous, since the information was outdated. For context, the *Requests* library does in a single statement what would have taken multiple statements and libraries. Without it, we had to rely on our Google-fu to get code that won't fail too easily.

I then added a disclaimer. But I got two more downvotes after that.

How can I retire an outdated accepted answer? Is it even my job?

Comment: The fact that it has a couple of downvotes now should warn future readers that this is not the way to go anymore. Though the disclaimer is fairly obvious too, I admit.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I believe its uncalled for. As a person looking for a solution, I have a duty to judge the answer sceptically before using it, the date and comments are sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: There is some good discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer  One thing about that answer though, it doesn't contain the solution, it links to your other answer that has the solution.  That might explain some of the downvotes. It seems like the consensus of the community that answers should be fully self contained is getting more strict as time goes on.

Comment: As for what to do about it, I think legacy answers serve their place, and should not be deleted or downvoted just because they address how things used to be. Who knows how many people are still using legacy systems, who would need to use your legacy solution.  A good example of what to do with such answers is this one from Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479

Comment: @DanielNugent, in most cases it's irrelevant how things use to be 10 years ago. This is a site for devs. People just want the answer to the question, something that works, and they don't want to go through all those edits.

Answer (score -1):

I do sort-of think it's your job to update your answers if they go out of date, but anyone can edit your answer (and you can edit other people's) so really it's a community job. When you notice something outdated, do something like this:

1. Add a warning at the top that it's out of date.
2. If there's another (currently correct) answer, refer to that from the warning. If not, write another answer and refer to that.
3. If an incorrect answer is the accepted answer, try to notify the OP with a comment to change the accepted answer.

I've just done that to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17208261/461492) - let's see if it works. The reason I think this is a good approach is that it solves the basic problem of "What would be the most useful information for someone coming to the page?". If they have to read through a few outdated questions with lots of votes (and possibly accepted) before seeing a new up-to-date and correct answer with just a few votes at the bottom, that's not as good as a quick notice highlighted at the top of the old answers that links straight to the better one.

Comment: Seems a bit noisy to me, but I'll be curious to see how other people think about what you did. Generally these kind of things are handled with a comment, not by editing in a glaring warning sign into multiple answers.

Comment: Well I generally start reading at the top of the first answer. That's the point at which I'd like to know if it's known-to-be-outdated. I might only read the comments if I don't understand the answer, or have some follow-up questions, or it didn't work - to see if others had the same experience. Just trying to figure out the "most useful" thing, for someone landing on the page.