# Surfacing newer, better, information about a popular tool

Tags: discussion

Coming from [Removing pip's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762308/1931274)

Since the question was asked in 2012, pip has obviously evolved and I just posted an answer there noting the current "here's how you can do things", with information about functionality added that's been added since, that directly addresses the question asked (and mentions "adjacent" new functionality related to it) and makes it easier/nicer to do so.

*puts on pip maintainer hat*

However, given that this question has a >500 votes accepted answer, I'm doubtful that this newly posted answer would ever get surfaced high enough for most users to see (I doubt even 1% of the traffic to the question would see something this low in such a question). Now, I know that a lot of pip's users will hit this page when they google around for a solution and not having the "here's the nicest ways you can do things with the recent versions" answer on top isn't ideal. I'd like this information to be surfaced, so that it makes the newly added functionality more discoverable and push adoption of those nicer approaches.

*puts down pip maintainer hat*

In theory, I have the required reputation to go and edit any of the posts appropriately but... all the approaches that I've come up with feel sub-optimal in some form:

1. Editing the question to add this information feels like putting the information in the wrong place.
2. Editing the accepted answer feels incorrect -- it clearly changes the original post far beyond what it was originally. Plus, it attributes the reputation to the wrong user. :)
3. Not doing anything hurts the discoverability of the functionality that's been added since the question/answer were posted. The newly posted answer may never actually come up high enough.
4. Adding a link from the currently-accepted-answer to the newly posted answer feels like the most appropriate tool (directs people to the current info, does not modify existing post's content, pushes users to upvote the newly posted answer); but also "feels wrong" from some reason that I'm not able to pin down.

What's the best way to deal with a situation like this?

---

Related Meta questions:

- [How to retire outdated information?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300347/how-to-retire-outdated-information): the information there is "outdated" in the sense that it's not the best way to do stuff now -- yes, but it'll still work. :shrug:
- [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer): the workarounds still work, but there are better ways to do this now; we've made changes to improve the UX in this space.
- [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers): it's not a bad answer, but it's not the best answer anymore.

Comment: That last related question has the standard answer(s): [Comment, downvote, answer, wait](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368702/215552). Not what you want to hear? Think up a better way of dealing with it and add a question on Meta tagged `feature-request`.

Comment: Right, except that my newer answer would never actually get enough traffic to even aggregate those upvotes. The issue isn't that the answer is "bad / incorrect" (like that question), but suboptimal -- there's a newer better approach that's better and works for nearly everyone (80% of PyPI downloads now happen with pip 20.1, almost all downloads happen with pip > 6.0).

Comment: None the less, I've gone ahead and commented as suggested by @HereticMonkey. I don't wanna downvote and, well, I'll wait for a few weeks now. If things are still not "boosted" high enough, I'll go with 4 above. If anyone has concerns with that, they're welcome to comment here / holler later. :)

Comment: @pradyunsg I'd not add a link to your answer to the top answer ... Imagine every other answerer would do that...

Comment: @JonasWilms I agree it'd be *really* bad if every other answerer did that. OTOH, not every other answerer is a maintainer of the tool that the question is about. I mean, I definitely don't wanna be reckless here / do unnecessary things, but more actively surfacing information from maintainers seems to be a good idea?

Comment: That someone is a "maintainer" of something does not necessarily mean that someone is able to write good answers.

Comment: @JonasWilms Fair. I want to argue that it's not the case in this specific instance but I don't think "one-off exceptions" like that would work for SO.

Comment: Looks like we just doesn't have any effective "tool" to use to fix the highly-upvoted-and-accepted-but-there's-better-answers-from-better-sources situation in a reasonable amount of time (no, I don't consider "years" as a reasonable timeline). I'm a little bummed about that but I can live with that, if that's our best answer as a broader community.

Comment: Related: [What's the etiquette on updating an accepted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402931/674039)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been addressed to a substantial degree by [Outdated Answers: accepted answer is now unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352), which is a site-wide change that better surfaces highly voted answers over accepted answers.

Notably, this has improve the situation for most of posts that motivated this question:

- [What is the meaning of "Failed building wheel for X" in pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204916/what-is-the-meaning-of-failed-building-wheel-for-x-in-pip-install/56504270#56504270)
- ["WARNING: Value for scheme.data does not match" when I try to update pip or install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244301/warning-value-for-scheme-data-does-not-match-when-i-try-to-update-pip-or-inst/67250419#67250419)

It still hasn't fixed the original post's issue, but I expect that'll actually get addressed properly given enough time; which is what @Jonas Wilms's answer suggests is expected.

Answer (score 6):

*Once there was a stone lying on the beach. A wave came and hit the stone. It looked like nothing changed, but slowly, as time passed by, the stone turned into sand.*

I know this is hard to believe because it happens so slowly. But good answers do really flow to the top. I've seen this multiple times.

<sub>But when they reach the top, they are usually outdated already.</sub>

---

Editing questions might remove the useful information that got them to the top initially, so better avoid that. Commenting is a good way of indicating outdated information.

Comment: Can confirm; all of my answers have turned to sand, too.

Comment: I guess? The concern I have: the question is the top hit on "pip cache remove" and talks about a bug that was fixed 6 years ago. The answer is not about removing the cache but about working around that bug -- so it doesn't actually answer users who've reached there via that search. Search engines will keep directing users here, and it's likely gonna be months (likely years) before the more relevant answers based on traffic patterns "fight back" the 100s+ upvotes here.

Comment: If our best answer is "just wait", I can live with that, knowing that I've done all I can here, using the best tools available. It just feels sub-optimally slow.