# Is it appropriate to change the accepted answer on an old question that now has a better answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked the following question 3 years ago: [Can you define optional docker-compose services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680958/can-you-define-optional-docker-compose-services)

At the time, there wasn't really a *good* way to do it, but the top-scoring answer was a reasonable solution, given the functionality of Docker Compose at the time.

As of December last year, there is now a much better way to solve the problem, using a new feature added to Docker Compose.

A user just added an answer to this effect.

If this were a brand new question, the latest answer would, by far, qualify as the accepted answer.

So, is it appropriate to change the accepted answer to this better answer?

Note, this is not the same as modifying the accepted answer ([What's the etiquette on updating an accepted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402931/whats-the-etiquette-on-updating-an-accepted-answer)); this is about changing which answer is marked as accepted.

Comment: I don't see why not. Accepting is fully within the hands of the question asker. You can accept any answer you want or none at all. Acceptance shouldn't really matter much, honestly. The site tends to put a lot more of emphasis on the accepted answer by pinning it than it really needs to.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Since we are yet to know what tools (if any) the ["outdated answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/11407695) project brings us (given the accepted answers are part of the problem), we have to handle things ourselves, so an answer that *could have* helped you better be it posted at the time you accepted another gets the mark (it has an added value that others tend to go for an accepted answer over the other ones)

Comment: Thanks - I don't recall seeing that in the listed of suggested questions, but that's a perfect fit. Thanks