# What is currently being done about outdated information on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-experience, product-support, stack-overflow-history

What are the specific, short, medium and long term efforts by the Stack Overflow team to reduce the overhead of weeding through answers containing outdated or outright inaccurate information?

I'm asking about current efforts to test new [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) for allowing the Stack Overflow community to efficiently deal with obvious bad information cluttering otherwise useful and relevant questions on this website.

The context for this question is well described in "[How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad and outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272584/4028977)"

Notes from that thread include:

- A "correct answer" at a given time should not need to be edited to completely swap out the solution.
- Existing answer should be preserved but also marked as out of date, similar to how Amazon sometimes indicates a "newer version of this product may be available."
- Active / Oldest Votes filters help some but not if people are adding comments trying to correct the most upvoted or "correct" answer.
- Having users spend points to reduce traction on an outdated answer, while upvoting a new correct answer is doubly wrong because it hurts the original author and it has a negative impact on the score of the voters.

I am both a user and sometimes answer author and editor. Stack Overflow is affected by a substantial amount of cruft, particularly in modern web technology and [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) where methodology has changed substantially over the past 3-5 years.

It does not seem that the current voting behaviors expected from crowds is effective, but rather a "retire this answer" option needs its own votable option which hides, but preserves answers deemed inaccurate.

I wrote this question because I scored 10 points this morning on an upvote to my answer in [this question regarding Alpine Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628472/can-i-install-pg-dump-without-installing-postgres-on-alpine/63948100#63948100). This is a good example of a "problematic" Stack Overflow Q/A setup that is draining time that people could be using to contribute to the Stack Overflow community.

Additional previous questions related to this topic: "[How to retire outdated information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300347/how-to-retire-outdated-information)?" and "[Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer)"

Comment: we are storing it, so future generations can read all about our bad practices. they'll have a blast.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Nothing :)

Comment: *"SO is affected by a substantial amount of cruft, particularly in modern web tech and devops where methodology has changed substantially over the past 3-5 years."* - Boy... I sure do wish _I_ got to use modern web tech instead of having to support ancient code bases that are older than I am... Good thing SO _has such a vast amount of "outdated" perfectly useful information for the users that don't have such luxuries_

Comment: Re *"...current efforts to test new UX"*: What current efforts are you referring to?

Comment: The duplicate target is an outdated one... A newer development is *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).

Answer (score 11):

There's only *so* much we could do to shield others from outdated or bad information, but the *reality* is...

- People have to use older software, for better or worse, for good or bad reasons.
- People will still copy and paste code from this site, believing that it is fit for purpose, no matter what labels we attach to it, or what we warn them on.

...but more fundamentally...

**People need to be prepared to do research.**  We are not always going to be right or accurate, and the people that just trust us implicitly will set themselves up for failure.  While we can provide the information, it's up to the individual to search for the right information they require to actually solve their problem.

Comment: I have no problem with people using old software, but should information be organized for 10% or 90% of content consumers?  Saying, do research is fine, people do that already, but why make them do even more than necessary? Is the point of this site to encourage research?

Comment: I mean, why stop there. If we really want people to do research, perhaps users could be pointed at the release notes for any given tool as the answer to any given question.