# Show warning if accepted answer is heavily outvoted by subsequent answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, upvotes, wrong-answers

The feature request "[Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/129164)" has a lot of upvotes, but is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Nevertheless, the problem of bad, wrong, or outdated accepted answers being prioritized over good, correct, current answers remains an issue I encounter pretty regularly (and therefore assume others do as well).

I'd like to propose an alternate solution. If answers are sorted by "Votes", and the accepted answer is significantly outvoted (say by 2x or 3x) by a subsequent answer, a banner should appear just above the accepted answer indicating this. Possible phrasing of this banner:

- This question has a few well-regarded answers! Be sure to check below to see if another answer might be better suited to your issue. *[proposed by @DanielF]*
- Warning: There are answers below with significantly more upvotes than this answer. *[my original suggestion]*
- Note: There are answers below with significantly more upvotes than this answer. *[same as above except "Note" instead of "Warning", as suggested by @HABO]*

Pros:

- Simple, minimalist solution to the problem of a weak accepted answer
- Reduces the temptation to downvote the accepted answer
- Keeps the accepted answer at the top, where people expect to see it
- Avoids any debate over how far down the page an accepted answer should appear
- Seemingly easier to implement than changing the sorting algorithm

Cons:

- Potentially insulting to the person who provided the accepted answer
- Adds clutter

Comment: I'd prefer "Note" to "Warning". (Thanks to M$ for making `ERROR_SUCCESS` the norm.) And, pedantically speaking, answers are generally ranked by _upvotes - downvotes_, not just _upvotes_.

Comment: @HABO, No objection to "Note", and I'm open to any wordsmithing people want to do. I just want there to be something to nudge people into looking beyond the accepted answer if there are better answers.

Comment: @anatolyg, When I say "subsequent", I just meant answers that appear after the accepted answer when sorted by Votes. I'm thinking no new sorting algorithms should be necessary.

Comment: Seems like a weird work-around to not wanting to unpin the accepted answer. I doubt slapping a _this answer is worse than others_ message on the  accepted answer will keep people from downvoting it, I'd expect downvotes to increase rather than decrease.

Comment: How about something like *"This question has a few well-regarded answers!  Be sure to check below to see if another answer might be better suited to your issue."*  Skip the "the marked answer sucks" implications entirely.  This would even work when you have multiple good answers - I've seen questions with multiple answers that solve the problem in multiple ways, each more suited to a certain end user. (Like a "Big Data" answer and a "small data" answer.)

Comment: "*the accepted answer is significantly outvoted (say by 2x or 3x) by a subsequent answer*" How many answers would actually be affected by this, I wonder? And what portion of them would be outside the 0-3 score range?

Comment: How about an Answer that is posted *later* than another Answer? The later Answer is accepted, but has a lower score. Why should that get a warning? Your definition of "subsequent" is just by the score, right? I mean this will make it an actual **disadvantage** to posting a better Answer, because if it gets accepted, then it will get this banner.

Comment: "Potentially insulting to the person who provided the accepted answer" people need to calm down. This is not insulting at all!

Comment: @Braiam maybe it is time to replace the checkmark with a lightbulb to convey the real meaning of "accepted": this answer inspired me the most solving my problem. *This is answer is so wrong that I finally saw the light and implemented the opposite Thanks for giving me that insight!*

Comment: How about we spend more time training people to read all of the answers to a question instead of the one that has a special icon next to it. I don't know how many times I've voted to mark a question as a duplicate and less than a minute later gotten the "no it doesn't" response because the accepted answer doesn't work for them. Every other of the 50 answers on the question do, but not the one with the green check mark, so nope! not a dupe.

Comment: @HereticMonkey "*How about we spend more time training people to read all of the answers to a question instead of the one that has a special icon next to it.*" I'd love for this to happen but I fear it might be impossible. I've seen people use SO - some that are familiar with the site in general but not how to extract information. One pattern I see often is that they'd focus on *the question*. Sure, it's important to see if it matches but they'd actually try the code and that already (usually) doesn't work. Hence the need for answers.

Comment: Yes, please! This might also prevent edits like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14373108) which are injecting later and more up-to-date answers into the accepted answer for convinces' sake and to the detriment of the person who actually came up with it.

Comment: Related [feature-request] on Meta.SE: [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666/348196) (one of the best suggestions, IMO)

Comment: @DanielF, I incorporated your suggestion into the feature request. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, When it comes to UI/UX, training should be a last resort (https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/12/its-not-a-training-issue.php). Given that a ton of folks come to StackOverflow questions via Google searches, the last thing we can reasonably expect is that they would want to break their flow by engaging with any sort of training. And even I, who knows full well that accepted answers are not necessarily the best, still finds myself walking down the "garden path" of the accepted answer, only to realize later there is a *much* better answer if I scroll down.

Comment: @devuxer "We can't expect people to learn/read/change" is something I hear every day. "We can't expect people to think for themselves" is what is really meant. Actually, I'm quite good at expecting people to do all of these things. Yes, I'm constantly disappointed when people don't meet my expectations :). But if we keep lowering our expectations, we're going to end up at the bottom of the heap with a bunch of drooling morons "writing" our software. I'm not willing to let that happen to the industry I've devoted more than half my not-inconsiderably long life to.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, For someone who strongly advocates reading, your response seems as if it resulted from reading only part of one sentence I wrote. I don't argue against developers being diligent in their work, but I do argue for designs that encourage people to fall into the "pit of success". Most developers come to StackOverflow on a mission to get help with their problem, not learn how to master StackOverflow. All I'm calling for with my proposal is to guide readers to the answer(s) that are most likely useful so they can make best use of their time.

Comment: Future readers should note that this is functionally [[meta-tag:status-obsolete]] now that [accepted answers are ranked by votes on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410859).

Comment: @zcoop98 probably better to add that tag rather than a comment ...

Answer (score 2):

While on its surface I agree with this feature request, [for reasons related to another answer I provided *recently*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402797/1079354) I must disagree with it being implemented.

To quote:

> **People need to be prepared to do research.**  We are not always going to be right or accurate, and the people that just trust us implicitly will set themselves up for failure.  While we can provide the information, it's up to the individual to search for the right information they require to actually solve their problem.

If an individual is only ever glued to the accepted answer as a trusted paragon of accuracy and will Solve the Problem™, we remove ourselves from the role of being a repository of information to being someone who is responsible for holding the hand of the new generation of developers.  Besides, problem solving is *really* the only skill engineers have and need to illustrate.  Copying an answer from Stack Overflow isn't problem solving.

Comment: I actually agree with your quoted statement, but I don't agree that it invalidates my proposal. Why? Because **this isn't about laziness**. I don't come to StackOverflow thinking, "I'm just going to read the first answer I see and blindly hope for the best." I, in fact, expect to read multiple answers. That said, I do tend to read the answers in the order they are presented. Since StackExchange is not willing to unpin the accepted answer even it's clearly not the best, I've tried to come up with an alternate way to get people to begin their answer-reading journey in a better place.

Comment: Also, please see the latest edit to my proposal, as I added an alternate wording for the banner (based on one of the comments). Maybe that will mesh better with your desire for people to take more personal responsibility.

Comment: This answer seems to fly in the face of the recent effort to update outdated answers. "We're not always going to be right" is a legal bum-cover, not the ideology we strive for. As evidenced by the recent initiative to update out-of-date answers. The votes are already recording a better answer in this scenario. It's worth noting, at the least.

Answer (score 2):

I'm may be going against the tide here, but I think this feature, though it wouldn't harm (we should provide as much information as possible to the user without compromising UI/UX), shouldn't be a priority.

We must trust the users not only to select the correct answer, but also to research the correct solution for the problem at hand. Another thing to note is that despite your experience, you will notice if an answer has twice the votes of an accepted answer, no matter the order of the answers, if not, well, that's the kind of lack of attention to detail that a programmer should not have.

In my own experience as an SO user for almost as long as I started programming, I have never relied on accepted answer status to get the best solution to my problem. Even when I was a newbie, as far as I can remember, I got my answers from a combination of comparing the answers (if more than one) and cross-comparing them with other information I had for the particular problem.

Without having recorded the stats (sadly), I think it's safe to say that there are rare instances where I rely solely on one answer, though there are a few notable ones from equally notable users that are textbook material, and we, as smart programmers, will identify them, even if they are not accepted.

I also quibble with one of your pros:

> - *Reduces the temptation to downvote the accepted answer*

Bad answers should be downvoted whether they are accepted or not.

Comment: The accepted answer is currently no longer pinned to the top.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier, when was this change implemented?

Comment: Not sure, a few weeks back I think?

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier thanks for the info. That being the case ther is no point in furthering this discussion.