# Which answer is right depends on when it was posted

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867973/c-sharp-interactive-window-in-vs-2015-ctp-6) about year ago. At that time [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872454/240564) was correct.

But now Microsoft fixed the problem with C# interactive windows, probably [this is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34019091/240564) now. Should I change the accepted answer?

Comment: Any question about a CTP for a product is essentially irrelevant once the actual version of that product has come out.

Comment: At the time asked, the accepted answer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really special case, and to draw meaningful ideas about a generic way to handle this situation from a response would be a mistake.

You asked a question about a preview product, which was answered. Once a product, the product was updated to include the missing functionality. In other words, someone has to still be using the preview version.

In this circumstance I don't think the standard caveats around assuming that everyone one's upgraded and the certainty of necessary questions about older products apply.

I would delete the question and its answers. The answers to your question are some of the more pointless things I've read recently - they're all essentially duplicates of each other and all most of them say is *"it's available now"*. Your question, though maybe relevant at the time, now seems to just be a potential vector for confusion, the reason why you wrote the question initially.

Comment: So this is not a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265433/2564301 because it's not about the "final" version of a product. (Oops; the proposed duplicate http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265433/2564301 is also about 'finished' products)