# Proper wording for a note in an answer that it is no longer valid

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, editing-help

I have been trying to follow the advice [over here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) when I run into out of date answers - specifically:

> ...edit the answer to indicate that the answer is outdated....leave a note, at the top, preferably in italics saying something like: "[Editor's note: this answer was applicable until version 1.x, but version 2.x was released on 1st Jan 2014]".

I believe in these cases, an edit is more appropriate than a comment because comments are intentionally temporary. Normally I just edit a note onto the accepted answer, and post an up to date answer with information about which version it applies to.

With the breaking changes to Apache 2.4 regarding access control, I've run into a few of these.

I recently ran into a question where the [accepted answer was awful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php) and the right answer was split into different approaches by two answers.

I used two different wordings...because <strike>I hate redundancy</strike> I was cleverly A-B testing. Wording 1:

> Update for Apache 2.4: This answer is correct for Apache 2.2. In Apache 2.4 the access control paradigm has changed, and the correct syntax is to use Require all denied.

This [edit was accepted twice](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11455409), including by the author, and rejected once, because

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Wording 2:

> This solution is correct for Apache 2.2, but in Apache 2.4 access control has changed. Use Require all denied for Apache 2.4.

This edit [was rejected by all three reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11455444), for the reason above.

I don't see a significant difference in the wording, so I think it's really hit-or-miss depending on the reviewer.

**What's the best approach to this type of edit to make it clear to reviewers that it is NOT intended to address the author?**

Comment: Couple of comments: I would have put that at the top of the answer instead of the bottom (and in italics). Also, I wouldn't have suggested the new correct syntax but wrote a new answer for that.

Comment: A reviewer *must* read the edit summary. Perhaps your summary was too succinct?

Comment: @RadLexus I hadn't been using summaries correctly, and in researching this question realized that they were too short. Still, I wanted to know if the edit itself could be improved.

Comment: @Tunaki - thanks. I'll try to put them at the top instead of the bottom, and just with a warning. My rationale for including the syntax is that often I just need a reminder of what it is, so it's helpful to have that in an answer at the top of the page than to have to scroll through the whole page, where my new answer will probably never make it near the top. I see that it does change the authorial intent though, and I always do leave an answer if there isn't one.

Comment: Have you considered that you could ask a new question regarding the new software version and answer it yourself, pointing out the differences between previous solutions? Not that you have to do this, but in some cases it's simply simpler to just have an updated question & answers in a new page.

Comment: *Update* caught my eye as the lead in your first wording. The second wording needs reading and parsing to get that it is about a version change, which is kind of buried (see what I did there)?

Comment: @Bakuriu You do understand that questions and their answers are for future users, right?  So creating a new question with a new answer is undermining other users who continue visiting the older question with the older answer.  Updating an older answer to indicate that specifically refers to behavior in a specific version of the software is going to help future users the most.

Comment: @cimmanon yes. If the question was about vision 1 it will help all future users of version 1. If a library changes really significantly it doesn't really make that much sense to even consider then the same library hence it's just better to ask a new question. Also you can always comment and link the other question to point users to the other one.

Comment: But that's not the case here.  The specific question is "How do I do X" with absolutely no version mentioned at all.  Questions regarding a *specific* version of software are typically written after that version has been superseded by a new version (eg. is it possible to use new feature X in old version Y?) or are asking about compatibility (eg. is version X compatible with library version Y?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summary from the comments:

1. Leave a good edit summary, with details about why you are making the edit.
2. Put information like this at the top of the post in italics, to make it more obvious to future users that the answer is version-dependent.
3. Don't put the fix in the answer; use a separate answer if there isn't one already detailing the fix.
4. Ensure that the word "Edit" or "Update" starts the edit, and that the version information is clear.

So something like this:

> *Edit: This answer is correct for version x. In y, abc changed.*

Comment: Another point: Don't reference another answer. By doing so, you upgrade the status of another answer, and degrade the status of the other, which simply isn't fair. Saying *Please follow X answer* is horrible.

Comment: Please do not use edit marks; point 4 is undesirable and unneeded.

Comment: @NathanTuggy But shouldn't it be clear that this is not part of the original answer? Because if they have version x, the answer is still correct.

Comment: @Josiah: It doesn't matter whether it's part of the original answer. That's why we have revision histories; SO is about making good final versions, not about displaying the whole torturous progress of enlightenment to every passerby. What *does* matter is that it's clear what the answer is actually correct for. But that could in principle have been there from the beginning, and would have been just as useful.