# Mark a previously accepted answer as deprecated?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed that there're a lot of really great questions that have trouble with aging, either due to language progression (like Swift) or just development of commonly used tools in the language (like JavaScript). In many of these cases, the older answer still has value but it needs to be updated.

These are more open-ended questions, but I'm curious at what would be the way to address this situation. Is there already any way to mark a previously accepted answer as deprecated so another time-relevant question may pop in? Or would the suggested route be to edit the answer to match? Or just leave it and answer again?

Comment: DANG. It is, didn't search well enough.

Comment: No worries :) Also related, specifically to the deprecated mark: [Proper wording for a note in an answer that it is no longer valid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320726/7795130)