# New answer, then Top answer update, then it looks like duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, answers

It starts with a simple question on a popular API (Google product, Facebook product, Twitter product, ...).

As we're not talking about techniques or algorithms, one short answer is enough and it gets many votes:

> Send them `my_submission(my_user: "me", my_result: 0)`

Then, Google or Facebook or Twitter decides to deprecate `my_submission` and adopts instead `submission`. So someone posts this as a new answer:

> Send them `submission(user: "me", result: 0)`

For a time, both APIs work and both answers collect votes. Then the initial top answer gets updated to be identical to the newer answer, as the old API is going to disappear anyway.

Current status, where both answers are identical:

- Question 80 votes
- Original answer updated 200 votes
- Newer answer 20 votes

Do I flag the newer answer for deletion?
Do I flag the older answer for conversion to community wiki?
If we keep both copies of an identical answer, aren't people going to lose their time and energy trying to figure out the correct voting strategy to adopt (upvote both, upvote the top one only, upvote the newer one only, etc.)?

Comment: This right here is why Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited and we encourage people to improve existing answers when there is a minor change that needs to be made. Sure, you *can* post a completely new answer, but that just creates problems. It would have been better if person 2 would have just tweaked answer 1 to either bring it in line with the current recommended API or just add both solutions. Then, we'd just have one good, highly-upvoted answer. No confusion, no mess, no hassle later on.

Comment: @CodyGray [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) might not be helping.

Comment: Instead of updating the old top answer to be identical to the new answer, I think it should have been edited to include both the new and the old method plus an explanation that the old method was deprecated from date X. The historical part may all so be of interest to someone that gets an old code base in their hand.

Comment: @4386427 you should make that an answer.

Comment: Sometimes I want to update an old answer but when it involves changing the code (which apparently is discouraged) it is easier to just add a new answer. Then I don't have to tiptoe around whether I am over editing the author's post. However, this has resulted several times in the situation you described above.

Comment: @Suragch there's nothing on the help center that discourages editing, in any way or form. It mainly asks you to respect the author.

Comment: I think people will add a new anser to gain reputation. If you edit someone else answer, only the origin author will receive the rep. Only on a minor change people will edit the existing answer. Otherwise always a new one will be created. The question will be how to solve this issue? On the one side the page should be clear without too much answers, on the other side the fake internet points are here to encourage people to add answers.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree, however the incentive system doesn't reward that behavior, and this is why we see many similar answers. It would be nice if after editing an answer if the editor(s) also received rep (up to a limit) when the answer was upvoted.

Comment: @CodyGray I think that person 2 would like to get his credit and votes. And for that, he would create a new answer.

Answer (score 19):

I think the old answer should have been updated to include both the old and the new versions, especially as it is most likely the accepted answer.

I would also add a mention for the newer correct answer, leading to an answer that looks like this:

> **For versions before x:**
>
> Send them `my_submission(my_user: "me", my_result: 0)`
>
> **For versions after x** (as @username has mentioned in [their answer below](http://google.com))
>
> Send them `submission(my_user: "me", my_result: 0)`

This way the accepted answer stays relevant, but the new answer still gets the credit it deserves.

I don't think the newer answer needs editing.

Comment: Maybe the newer answer can do the inverse: "for older versions see older answer...", and that way everyone would be happy. :)

Comment: @EMBarbosa fair point, but then you still have the problem of the accepted answer being out of date. Unfortunately, a significant amount of posts that have this problem were by users that no longer visit the site, so aren't going to swap the accepted answer to the new one.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the old answer don't should be edited also. Just that the new one could be too (*maybe*). That way, the older answer autor doesn't would be tempted to edit his answer to be a copy of the newer. Swapping the accepted one shouldn't be done by community anyway.

Comment: For this would be great if we were having those frames like documentation had (we could go deeper that a registered user could add version tag into favorites and fold them irrelevant frame, but that would require some version tag sorting).

Answer (score 2):

I would have edited both answers to make the dates/versions clearer.

For example:

> ### Before V2.3.0
>
> Send them `my_submission(my_user: "me", my_result: 0)`

> ### Since V2.3.0+
>
> Send them `submission(my_user: "me", my_result: 0)`

Well in this specific case, the API has changed and the older version probably won't be used anymore. But I think keeping both answers may be useful: If people are wondering why their code is no longer working, they will soon see that the API has evolved by seeing these two answers.

Answer (score -1):

So to use an academic analogy, what we have here is lack of guaranteed participation of all co-authors in the citations ranking and lack of joint awards.

If **answers co-authorship** was introduced, then younger colleagues that actually made the new discovery could "join" the publication of their tenured professor and start collecting citations (building reputation) together, without affecting relative ranking between them.

Co-authorship could solve yet another problem - the race at the expense of quality, with identical answers separated by just a few minutes that currently cannot be accepted together to get the "joint prize" like they would normally be in the academic awards (even if their publication dates were separated by a few... years).

That would also realize the principle of Collaborative Editing (the two editors would be turned from competitors into collaborators, because their incentives would start to be perfectly aligned, just like in academic teams that work together on a single publication, also across borders).

Comment: And wouldn't that encourage pointless trivial edits that don't add anything at all to the answer just to get a share of the reward?

Comment: I agree that this is possible, but the academic publishing world has dealt with it. One solution would be some form of peer review on permitting such co-authorship, with extra voting system (like currently on closing or reopening).

Comment: sounds like a lot of overhead when we have many people simply able to edit without review right now. We'd need to approve all edits, that's not scalable.

Comment: OK, but I bet an ML model could flag edits automatically as those that incorporate existing answers, using text similarity measures, references made to other posters nicks (which is used in attributions) and aided by a user-generated feature flag: "This answer incorporates another answer". To avoid overload with many small edits, I would use periodic polling, e.g. randomly spaced daily updates of model's input data.

Comment: Feel free to create one and test it by applying it to all the existing answer edits using SEDE. If you can prove it works flawlessly I'm sure it would be considered.

Comment: I think a Kaggle competition could do the job nicely (and inexpensively: with prizes being SO reps / bounties and gold/silver/bronze "Kaggler" badges).

Comment: Good luck simply reviewing my sole edits. [^_^](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/cœur?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Comment: The good news is that the modellers can ignore small diffs here (and concentrate on those that roughly double the answer in size over optimal historical aggregation periods), because old answer is usually kept unchanged, usually with special keywords like "before"/"old"/"original"/"<=" (another distinguishing feature separating it from normal edits)). And conditioning on other posters content and actions (sequence of events) would be probably much stronger related than relying on champion's edits history (which can be of course entirely independent and original as you pointed out).

Answer (score -2):

Yet another idea, now definitely scalable, and quite close to how reputation sharing works in the academia.

Why not propagate reputation to the authors of linked answers like we propagate reputation (citations counts) to the authors of cited academic papers or to linked websites (with incoming hyperlinks counts boosting Page Rank scores)?

*An illustration*

Here's a chain of three answers, recursively nested. The top tier collected disproportionate share of the points given relative age of the other chain links:

[Top Tier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257449/9962007) -> [Middle Tier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23728630/2213647) -> [Bottom Tier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464693/7851470) -> [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

*More details*

The system could automatically propagate reputation points to the authors of a limited number of linked answers (ideally only the first one), and linked either by the original author or by a highly reputable third party editor, e.g. gold badge holders in one of the original tags.

- All points collected by the two higher tiers could be added to each
  of the two lower ones (possibly also recursively, but after tests and with some nesting sanity limits to avoid Ponzi schemes)
- Linking times should be respected, to avoid sharing
  historical reputation that the subsequent author(s) did not earn. This will also maintain relative ranks (e.g. the Top tier will likely remain so thanks to the original reputation, and will continue growing thanks to the refreshed viability, but no longer at the expense of co-authors reps).
- Adding an outgoing link to another answer is currently free, and
  should arguably stay so, but this may require changing after tests: subtracting e.g. 2 reputation points for each outgoing link would possibly prevent giving reps away to friends and colleagues (and act as a natural limit on the maximum nesting level). This is similar to how bounties are currently allocated, but arguably will reach a larger scale thanks to lower cost (smaller impact on the benefactor's score).
- Reciprocal (circular) linking should not be permitted to avoid voting
  rings.