# What can I do seeing outdated question?

Tags: support, questions, outdated-information

***My question differ from [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433), because in my case question is outdated too, not only an answer.***

I found such a question: [How to center Google Map on a country by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744283/how-to-center-google-map-on-a-country-by-name)

This question concerns Google Maps API v2, which is expired now and I think that can be confusing for readers. What can I do to improve this situation? Should I ask new question but considering API v3 or maybe question can be edited to broad its scope? In first situation, should original question be closed? I'll add that among answers we have one considering API v2 and one for API v3 too (but less voted).

Comment: Since that question isn't tagged with any specific version you can just add a new answer for the new API version

Answer (score 4):

Since there's already an answer for the newer version, there's no need to ask a new question. (And if there hadn't been an answer but you knew one, you could just add it.) In this case you can just edit the question so it covers both versions of the API. Either remove the specific part about version 2, or (better, I think) add a note about the version 3 answer so that people searching will know they're in the right place.

In the case where there is no existing answer for a newer version, and you don't know one, I think it's ok to add a new question that points out the difference with the old one. (Link to the old question, say that you tried the answers there, show how they didn't work in the new version...)