# Should I post a new answer or edit my old answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I posted an answer to a question about 2 years ago, and it gets an occasional up-vote. Not anything to write home about but enough that I get a notification and re-read my answer.

I have since developed new habits, and while my original answer is still relevant, I have found more efficient/simpler ways to do the same thing. I would like to share the newer content, as I believe it would be helpful to others.

Should I **append** the new content to my old answer, or just compose a second **unique** answer?

Comment: Not enough relevant info, nobody can make that call but you.  Completely rewriting an answer is not wrong.

Comment: Relevant -  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer

Comment: inb4: So, it's ok to rewrite your own answer, but they call foul when correcting a minor inaccuracy or clarifying the meaning!?

Comment: I don't intend to rewrite anything, and the new content, is just another way to skin a cat, not a new cat entirely.

Comment: question edited for clarity

Comment: You can post a new answer, you can append to the existing answer, you can replace the existing answer, you can do nothing. All valid options depending on the situation which includes the state of the question and the state of the existing answer. Given that you only have a very high level description, its impossible to really say what is the more proper way forward. Do what allows you to sleep at night.