# What happens if a question becomes obsolete?

Tags: support, questions, old-questions

I've been looking through the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) && [enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enums) tags on Stack Overflow.

I noticed this question asking about an Xcode crash: [Enum crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305017/swift-xcode-getting-internal-errors-when-using-enums)

This question was posed over four years ago, and the crash has been fixed for some time.

I do not want to flag the question, because there is nothing that fits: "it's obsolete".

- Should I flag the post as "in need of moderator intervention" and just say "it's obsolete"
- When a post is taken down because it was obsolete, does the rep earned also get taken away?
- Or is this not a big deal, shall we leave it up?

All other questions on meta asking about obsolete questions are marked as duplicate to this one: [Obsolete answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer). This linked post only talks about obsolete answers, not the questions themselves. The question I'm asking about currently doesn't have answers.

---

Looking at a bigger picture, it might be hard to determine whether a post is obsolete, since people might still be using that software or still need it.

---

Ah, now that I'm thinking, I figured out an up-to-date answer to the question: "Update your Xcode"

Comment: People still use software every day that others would consider "obsolete". The fact that an upgrade is available doesn't make the question obsolete. That just makes for a good answer. And not even the *only* answer, because there are situations where you can't upgrade to the latest version and need a workaround for this one.

Comment: What did you learn researching this googling site:meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @CodyGray That's a very good point. If they cannot make the upgrade, that would make the workaround answer all the more difficult and intriguing.

Comment: @philipxy I saw that one, but it only addresses what to do if the accepted answer is out of date.

Comment: "out of date" is "obsolete".