# Should I flag comments posted by a user trying to draw attention to their answer?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, old-questions

On an old question from 2011 with 20 answers, a user has posted a new answer and then immediately left a comment on the question directing users to their answer. A "check this answer out for a new way to do it" type thing. The answer is from a high-rep user and presents a novel way of solving the question but I was thinking the comment should be flagged as "no longer needed." Is this an appropriate flag to raise on the comment or should I just ignore it?

Comment: Yes, flag it as no longer needed. The OP would have got a notification about the answer anyway.

Comment: Do you think the comment is needed any longer? I'd say "no" but I'm open to reasoning for the opposite.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't think it was ever needed. The OP will be notified of new answers and – according to SO prophecy – good answers will always rise to the top

Comment: @miken32 I think you answered your question for whether to flag NLN, in that case.

Comment: Is it a "new" way just because the answer is new, or because the content of other answers is outdated? The latter can be quite helpful on Q&A that have accumulated votes over the ages.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that's what gave me pause. But at the same time, there is a sort option for showing new answers first. The older answers are outdated and more verbose, but still functional.

Comment: I'll argue it depends on the type of comment. if it's clear it's a massively pointless comment, flag. If it, however, points out specific flaws with the answer(s) it's posted to, that's more in the realm of accepted comments

Comment: The problem with 'The OP will be notified' is that the OP might not be on SO anymore or lost interest. SO is not answering questions to SO only it is answering to _all_ users searching for answers to equal or similar questions. (Actually this is one of the flaws of SO: answer-rot.

Comment: Comments on such old answers should not be for the benefit of the OP but for anyone who happens to come across it.

Comment: I'm sure the new trending sort will bring this awesome new answer to the top anyway? 

Comment: @CaiusJard it will when the answer got some upvotes but when the answerer posted the comment immediately after posting the answer, the answer obviously has no upvotes at this point and the purpose of the comment is precisely to solve this (a kind of bootstrapping of the “trending” feature)

Comment: Wouldn't the comment help to point users to a newer, more updated answer at least meanwhile their question does not get to the top? At the end of the day, SO is supposed to leave those questions there for more people to find.

Comment: @S.Dre where does that leave us when every new answer to a question gets its own comment saying "me, me, look at me!"

Comment: If it is not a case where it is useful, I would flag it @miken32 . But there are cases where they can be useful.

Answer (score 30):

Depends on usefulness of the comment - it is not against the rules to bring up attention to flaws of answers (either due to changes in tech or any other reasons).

If comment is more like "I posted new awesome answer - check that out and upvote" - flag as "no longer needed" and move on. On other hand a comment highlighting changes in tech like "Most answer suggest approach using Foo.123, but now with Foo.456 there are alternatives - make sure to review all answers (I provided one)" worth keeping for some time.

I would check if "the new answer" shows high enough with whatever default sorting is at the moment (I think trending eventually will be default) and include that information to decide when to flag. I personally expect people to review at least first 2-3 answers so the comment suggesting to read one of those is NLN for me.

Note that it may be good idea to add comment (or even edit) to the top (by sorting) "old" answer to specify that it is no longer the only option with comment/edit similar to "This answer uses Foo.123 which was only option prior Bar.2.3, if using Bar.2.3+ review other answers".

Comment: Yes, very much in the "I posted new awesome answer" category. Flagged and removed.

Comment: Related meta question, [Good question, old version-dependent answer - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) -- there's option to edit the old answer to say "This answer is only applicable for version X." if that's the case

Answer (score 4):

Offhand I'd say this is not the kind of thing we'd like to encourage on the site by way of example, so I'd be inclined to flag it.

I can think of two exceptions though.  If the comment was directed to a specific user via `@` it could be useful until you know that user had seen it.  And if the underlying technology has changed in a way that affects the existing answers, that could be worth drawing attention to.

Answer (score 1):

I generally don't *comment* to "go read my answer", though I will credit other folks' answers if referenced in my own posts. This is doubly true if the other answer on the same question is well written, expounds further than my answer does (in this case I've likely edited in a recommendation to read the other answer if I feel it complements my own), or if I'm providing an extension of another answer (e.g. "To expound further on @Soandso's helpful answer...." with a link of course). I will also sometimes link to another answer of my own in a post if I feel it will offer additional clarity, making sure to be clear that it is **also my answer**.

If the answer if a community wiki, I don't think I've even come across any community wiki answers on the main site myself. I suppose in that case I think I would simply edit the wiki-answer with any additional relevant information, making commenting about the new information a moot-point in that case.

---

The one exception for me is that I will sometimes comment under a question or answer to one of my own answers on *another* question if it expounds further on some detail (and wouldn't qualify as a duplicate of the question), explaining why they may want to review it. I generally do this rarely and only if I feel the additional information might help the poster. This is especially true if I feel the information isn't at the core of the question or answer but the poster demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of how the subject works.

I can't find examples of any *comments* where I've done this as I don't do it very often. To offer an example context though, I do sometimes share [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676) in comments when I feel the user could use an explanation of how redirection and output streams work in PowerShell, and I have not or would not be able to provide an answer to the poster's question. And again, the case for doing so hinges on whether the post author demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of redirection or output streams in the first place.